# How to capture key press event with table cell - Web Accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have accessbility enable web application

In table on cell I have data which is being read by screen reader JAWS. On the same cells I have menu which is being activated on enter key press.
I donot have any role defined on cell. Its as follow:

Issue 1. Enter key press converted to mouse click event Jaws doing it,as without Jaws ON, its works fine. so how to make enter key work here .
I have 2 different menu to open on mouse click and enter key press.

Below is the sample code where when jaws is ON enter key press become click event.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



     $( "td" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });

    $("td").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
      }

    });



});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table> 
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Parameter</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td tabindex="0" >function</td>
    <td>Specifies </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>function2</td>
    <td>Optional.</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: intial table]

---

[image: After mouse click]

Comment: I have a few questions to make sure I understand what you're doing and what you want.  How does a sighted mouse user interact with your table?  Do they click on a cell and get a menu?  Is there a visual indication that clicking on a cell is going to pop something up?  Is the table a 'standard' data table that has column and possibly row headers and then rest is data?  Does clicking on a cell pop a menu or does it cause the cell to go in edit mode?

Comment: 1. Sighted user interact with mouse. 2.  Yes they click on cell and get menu. 3. there is no visual indication its know to user. 4 . table is standard data table its has rows, row header and columns. 5. there is no editing on cell readable cell.

Comment: @user0011 *"Sighted user interact with mouse"*. They can interact with a keyboard, with an eye-tracking device, with a touchscreen, with their voice, with their feet, with the contraction of their cheek. If you really want to make it accessible, be sure to handle all those devices. Forget the `font` element, the `outline: none` css. Do not convert a `div` to a button, when you can use a `button` element.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example, or some other online test playpen that we can try?  If not, how about some screenshots of the initial table and then what it looks like with a mouse click.  I'm glad you're asking about accessibility and there's a great community here with a wealth of knowledge in that area but we can only help so much given limited information.  I suspect my fellow accessibility specialists are thinking there are more issues with this app than your initial question.

Comment: when enter is pressed on cell it supposed to open different menu than click (this menu is more option for blind user). menu opining is same as attached image

Comment: @slugolicious, Added a sample code

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue where JAWS converts a `keypress` event  made on a table cell (`TD`) into a `click` event made on an anchor tag within that table cell. A `keypress` event handler on the table cell is never fired and the link within is navigated to instead.

The solution I've found is to add an `aria-hidden` to the anchor tag when the table cell is selected and then remove it when the table cell is no longer selected. In order to keep the screen reading functionality in place, I also have to copy the anchor tag's `aria-label` attribute up to the table cell when the table cell is selected and then move it back to the anchor tag when the cell is no longer selected.

It's horribly hacky but so is JAWS, unfortunately. I hope something similar works for you!